# CSS border for inside div

Tags: css, html

How to apply right border for inner div?

```
.outerDiv{width:100%;} 
.leftDiv{float:left;width:10%;}
.centerDiv{float:left;width:80%;}
.rightDiv{float:left;width:10%;}
.divContent{float:left}

 <div class="outerDiv"> 
     <div class="leftDiv">First</div> 
     <div class="centerDiv">
          <div class="divContent">inside1</div> 
          <div class="divContent">inside1</div> 
          <div class="divContent">inside1</div> 
     </div> 
     <div class="rightDiv">Third</div> 
 </div>
```

Output:

```
---------------------------
first|inside1      | third|
     |inside2      |      | 
     |inside3             |
---------------------------
```

The content (second column) border is not aligned properly.

Comment: right border not touching the bottom line, because it applying the border only for content height

Comment: Is it possible to put fixed height?

Comment: my requirement is, content goes increase the div also increase accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I see some flaws in your code.

First off, it appears that you want inside 1,2 & 3 to be lined up vertically, not horizontally.  Just remove the `float` for this.  Even though you talk about borders, you don't show any of them in your CSS.

Start with this fiddle.  Clarify your question if this doesn't do what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/zCpXM/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have different options:

When you know your maincontent has always the biggest height, just declare border-left and border-right on it: http://jsfiddle.net/NSgxH/ This way the borders will always go to the bottom.

If you cant make this assumption you can use display table to fix this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NSgxH/3/ This however will cause issues in older IEs.

There are several other techniques to achieve the same result including fixed heights, negative margin-tricks and so on, but I would say the above are the cleanest solutions.